# How start first activity ? (not always)

Tags: android

I ran "Main" when i click button "exit"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(intent);
```

and then i return on my application and see... it's not first "activity".. this is  my last "activity"

**how can I set the program ... begin with the first activity?**

Only when I click "exit"

i have:
[1] activity [2] activity [3] [4]

when i pressed "exit" in [4] or [3] activity  i go "Main" and then  if i start  or return app i again create [1] activity
if i "turn back" or pressed button "down button" and return app i start "onResume()" when i pressed this buttons

Comment: I'm not sure what is the hierarchy of your activities. Are you trying to return to your root activity (which you start from launcher) by clicking Exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in first activity (major activity)

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

and button "exit" add next code

```
    Intent goIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                [activity].class);
        goIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(goIntent);
```

Comment: well, that's interesting indeed :) `android.os.Process.killProcess()` is not something you use everyday. You sure achieved the desired behavior, but are you sure the resulting user experience is optimal? If some kind of behavior is so difficult to implement, that's probably not the way things should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting [android:clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) attribute to `<activity>` tag of your main activity(starting activity)

If you want to clear the task only upon pressing "Exit" button in your activity, you can call `finish()` in that activity before starting home activity. However this applies only if you have exit in the second activity.

Comment: android: clearTaskOnLaunch will also work if I press the button the system, so I do not need to

Comment: i have 4 activity, if i "exit" in 3 or 4 activity and used "finish()", i destroy 3 or 4 activity

Comment: one way is, to have a static flag(exited=true), set that flag onclick of 'exit' button, then on resume of each activity check that flag and finish the activity if the value is true. Reset the flag in the first activity onResume().

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the way you create the `Intent`. Probably these two statements

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

make Android think that your `MainActivity` is started from launcher, so full navigation stack is restored and you see the latest started activity. I suggest removing these lines.

The following code to start your `MainActivity` should work fine:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: MainActivity.class - its not Intent.ACTION_MAIN MainActivity.class probably its my "[1] activity" ... it works but i need exit app // i need Intent.ACTION_MAIN

Answer (score 0):

You can try

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);